# Sum result of a custom private function inside method eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to find the best way to do this:

I have a model with a `revenue` attribute and a private function inside model:

```
public function getProfit() {
    //Some logic with revenue attribute
}
```

I want to do something similar like this but with the `getProfit()` function

```
Model::all()->sum("revenue")
```

My goal is get the sum of all `getProfit()` results of all database `Model` items.

Thanks for all!

Comment: what do you want to get in the end? you want a "sum" of the `getProfit` call on each? ... why not make an accessor which you can use as an attribute?

Comment: My goal is get the sum of all `getProfit ()` results of all database model items for print in a view

Comment: well you can pass a callback to `sum` to tell it what to be "summing" ... or create an accessor for `profit` and you can use that with `sum` directly  `sum('profit')`

Comment: Make an anccessor was my first idea but I would see if there are a better option, I will try both. Thanks @lagbox

Comment: Finally with accesor works well.